# How to check if a column filter already applied into collection

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, collection

I want to check if a column `entity_id` filter already applied into collection.

**For eg**: Product collection has already applied `entity_id` **filter** where `entity_id in (1,2,3)`  etc.

So i want to check that if **collection** already has entity_id filter .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$collection->getFilter('entity_id');
```

And method definition

```
 /**
     * Search for a filter by specified field
     *
     * Multiple filters can be matched if an array is specified:
     * - 'foo' -- get the first filter with field name 'foo'
     * - array('foo') -- get all filters with field name 'foo'
     * - array('foo', 'bar') -- get all filters with field name 'foo' or 'bar'
     * - array() -- get all filters
     *
     * @param string|string[] $field
     * @return \Magento\Framework\DataObject|\Magento\Framework\DataObject[]|void
     */
    public function getFilter($field)
    {
        if (is_array($field)) {
            // empty array: get all filters
            if (empty($field)) {
                return $this->_filters;
            }
            // non-empty array: collect all filters that match specified field names
            $result = [];
            foreach ($this->_filters as $filter) {
                if (in_array($filter['field'], $field)) {
                    $result[] = $filter;
                }
            }
            return $result;
        }

        // get a first filter by specified name
        foreach ($this->_filters as $filter) {
            if ($filter['field'] === $field) {
                return $filter;
            }
        }
    }
```

I think you can take it from here :)